# rendering the models from collection in underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have to call models from iterating collection in underscore template but getting some trouble to understand logic. My code so far;

```
define(function (require) {
var _ = require("underscore");
var $ = require("jquery");
var backbone = require("backbone");
var BreederDecision_Model = require("model/BreederDecision_Model");
var BreederDecision_Collection = require("collection/BreederDecision_Collection");
var templateText = require("text!../templates/BreederDecision-template.html");

var prototype = {
    breederDecision_Model: null,
    breederDecision_Collection: null,
    breederDeferred : $.Deferred(),
    el: '#breederDecision'
};

prototype.initialize = function (options) {
    var self = this;
    self.breederDecision_Model = new BreederDecision_Model();
    self.breederDecision_Collection = new BreederDecision_Collection();
    self.breederDecisionTemplate =  _.template(templateText);
};
    //hear i have to call models from collection by underscore template
    prototype.render = function () {
        var self = this;
        var jqXHRBreeder = self.breederDecision_Collection.fetch();
        //var breeder_Collection = new BreederDecision_Collection();
        /*breeder_Collection.fetch({
            success : function(breeder_Collection) {
             var template = _.template($('#breeder-list-template').html(), {breeder_Collection: breeder_Collection.models});
             self.$el.html(template);
            }
        });*/

        jqXHRBreeder.done(function (){
                $.when.apply($, jqXHRBreeder).done(function () {
                    _.each(self.breederDecision_Collection.models, function(model) {
                        self.$el.html(self.breederDecisionTemplate({
                            'breederDecisionNoteId': model.attributes.breederDecisionNoteId,
                            "noteText": model.attributes.noteText

                        }));
                    });
                });
                //var abc = self.breederDeferred.resolve(self.breederDecision_Collection);
        });
    };

return backbone.View.extend(prototype);
});
```

Also i have created html templateto view the DOM.

```
    <script type="text/template" id="breeder-list-template">
<div id="breederDecision-view">

    <h2>Breeder Decision</h2>
    <hr/>
        <!--BreederDecision template -->
        <div id="breederDecision" class="col-sm-3">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                <% _.each(breeder_Collection, function(breederDecision_Model) { %>
                    <tr>BreederDecision_NoteId
                            <td>
                                <%= breederDecision_Model.get('breederDecisionNoteId')  %>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>BreederDecision_NoteText
                            <td>
                                <%= breederDecision_Model.get('noteText')  %>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

My Model so far:

```
define(
function (require) {
    var backbone = require("backbone");

    var prototype = {
        "breederDecisionNoteId" : "Unknown",
        "noteText" : "Unknown"
    };

    return backbone.Model.extend(prototype);
});
```

My collection so far:

```
define(function (require) {
"use strict";
var backbone = require("backbone");
var breederDecisionModel = require("model/BreederDecision_Model");
var ServiceUrls = require("../service-url");

return backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:breederDecisionModel,
    url:function () {
        return new ServiceUrls().getGWSRefData();
    }
});
});
```